# Docker EXPOSE vs command line -p option (boot2docker)

Tags: networking, docker, boot2docker

After spending way too long trying to access my node server running from a docker container within a boot2docker instance I realised the issue came down to a difference between expose and docker run -p.

In my Dockerfile I had EXPOSE 3001, and I could not access this via my host machine.

After running "docker run -p 3001:3001 myappinst myapp" I was able to access the port.

Up until now I thought "docker run -p 3001:3001" was essentially the same as EXPOSE 3001 in the dockerfile.

I noticed however, when running docker ps

I get the following for "EXPOSE":

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
16341e2b9968        housemation-crawler:latest   "npm start"         2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        3001/tcp            housemation-crawler-inst`

(note: 3001/tcp)

vs the below with `docker run -p 3001:3001`

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
0b14f736033c        housemation-crawler:latest   "npm start"         8 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:3001->3001/tcp   housemation-crawler-inst`

(0.0.0.0:3001->3001/tcp)

Looks like the latter is doing some kind of port forwarding, whereas the former is just opening up the port? Would that be right?

If I wanted to access a non forwarded exposed port how would I go about doing so? Also, if I wanted to have port forwarding within the dockerfile, what would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assumptions about how `EXPOSE` in `Dockerfile` and `-p` option in `docker run` are right. As you can read in [Docker on line documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#expose):

> `EXPOSE <port> [<port>...]`
>
> The EXPOSE instructions informs Docker that the container will listen
>   on the specified network ports at runtime. Docker uses this
>   information to interconnect containers using links (see the Docker
>   User Guide) and to determine which ports to expose to the host when
>   using the -P flag. Note: EXPOSE doesn't define which ports can be
>   exposed to the host or make ports accessible from the host by default.
>   To expose ports to the host, at runtime, use the -p flag or the -P
>   flag.

So the `EXPOSE` instruction in Dockerfile will indicate Docker which ports have to map to host if you run the container with the `-P` flag; but the local ports mapped are not deterministic and are chosen by Docker at run time. Apart from this, Docker will use the ports in `EXPOSE` to export information as environmental variables in linked containers.

If you want  to set the local port mapped, you have to use the `-p` option in `docker run`.

Comment: So does this expose the remote fs of the Linux instance docker is running ? I am trying to work out how I can have my local IDE connect to a remote docker instance.